# How can I prevent a test from timing out depending on tested statements?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a simple test case where I query my server and check the result, however the test times out. The test suite is running in a docker container along another container for the database.

The test itself looks like this

```js
import apolloServer from './testApolloServer';
import databaseWrapper from './databaseWrapper';

it('Should respond correctly', async () => {
    await databaseWrapper.createDocumentA();
    const docA = await databaseWrapper.retrieveDocumentA();

    await databaseWrapper.createDocumentB();
    const docB = await databaseWrapper.retrieveDocumentB();

    const response = await apolloServer.executeOperation(some_graphql_query);

    expect(response).toHaveProperty('data');

});
```

```
Result: TIMEOUT
```

This test timeouts (for 5000ms, or 10_000ms and even 20_000ms). If I comment out the database operations the test finishes on time:

```js
it('Should respond correctly', async () => {
    // await databaseWrapper.createDocumentA();
    // const docA = await databaseWrapper.retrieveDocumentA();

    // await databaseWrapper.createDocumentB();
    // const docB = await databaseWrapper.retrieveDocumentB();

    const response = await apolloServer.executeOperation(some_graphql_query);

    expect(response).toHaveProperty('data');
});
```

```
Result: Test fails but resolves
```

If I comment out the server execution the test finishes on time:

```js
it('Should respond correctly', async () => {
    await databaseWrapper.createDocumentA();
    const docA = await databaseWrapper.retrieveDocumentA();

    await databaseWrapper.createDocumentB();
    const docB = await databaseWrapper.retrieveDocumentB();

    //const response = await apolloServer.executeOperation(some_graphql_query);

    // expect(response).toHaveProperty('data');
});
```

```
Result: Test passes (no assertions)
```

However the addition of time of both operations does not break the timeout threshold.
I have not been able to find an answer in jest's docs or issues, having tried:

- `--runInBand`
- `jest.useFakeTimers('legacy')`
- `jest.useRealTimers()`

One thing I have managed to find out is that the first statement never resolves (`await databaseWrapper.createDocumentA();`) in the case where I leave the whole test to run (tested by adding a console.log before & after, and to prevent stdout from being caught by jest also by writing to a ./debug file).

I'm wondering if jest overloads the imports and tries to lazy-import modules during the test, maybe slowing it down to the point where it times-out, but I can't explain how it would resolve if I test it only one part at a time and not both -- unless the "lazy importing" of both modules break one another.

Useful to know

- the project needs building with babel (for import/export & typescript)
- tests run by calling `jest` (I'm guessing it discovers the need for babel and runs it itself, might be related?)

Comment: Small update, tried moving the object creations to a `beforeAll` hook but the same behaviour is observed.
If I leave the apolloServer query the `beforeAll` hook fails, but as soon as I comment the apolloServer query line the `beforeAll` hook passes in acceptable time...